# Circulant adjacency matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

I have a symmetric $n*n$ adjacency circulant matrix with a band structure given as follows:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &1&.&.&0 \\
1 &0 &1&1&.&.\\
1 &1 &.&.&.&.\\
. &1 &.&.&.&1\\
0 &. &.&.&.&1\\
0 &. &.&1&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
The elements in the diagonal take the value zero. There is a band of size $M(n)$ and the elements in that band take the value $1$. I have $\dfrac{M(n)}{n}=0$ as  $n \to \infty$.

I'am interested on finding the limiting eigenvalue distribution of this specific matrix.

My first though was to use the following property:

If $C \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a circulant matrix. Then its eigenvalues have the form (e.g. [here](http://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.pdf) [PDF])
$$\lambda_k = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} c_j  \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n} k\right), \tag1$$
where $c = (c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{n - 1})$ is the first row of $C$.

Applying this result I get the following expression for my matrix:
$$ \lambda_{k}= \sum\limits_{\substack{k=0}}^{n-1}{t_{k} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n} k\right)}= \sum\limits_{\substack{k=0}}^{M(N)}{t_{k} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n} k\right)}+\sum\limits_{\substack{k=n-2M(N)}}^{n-1}{t_{k} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n} k\right)}\\ $$
From $k=0$ to $k=M(n)$, $t_{k}=1$ otherwise zero. thus, we just keep the first sum of the previous expression.

$$\lambda_{k}=\sum\limits_{\substack{k=0}}^{M(n)}{\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n} k\right)}=\left[ \dfrac{\sin\Big(\frac{\pi k}{n}(2M(n)+1)\big)}{\sin\big(\dfrac{\pi k}{n}\Big)} \right] -1 $$

But when I let $n \to \infty$, I get an indeterminate form and the limit is not computable. Is there any possible trick to handle that kind of matrices.